# .htaccess rewrite returning Error 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)public_url=([^&]+)($|&)
RewriteRule ^process\.php$ /api/%2/? [L,R=301]
```

Where `domain.tld/app/process.php?public_url=abcd1234` is the actual location of the script.

But I am trying to get .htaccess to make the URL like this: `domain.tld/app/api/acbd1234`.
Essentially hides the `process.php` script and the get query `?public_url`.

However the script above is returning error 404 not found.

Comment: So this is meat to change the visible URL from the actual location of the object to the pretty URL. And how is that pretty URL then handled, if a request to it hits your http server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are actually looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)public_url=([^&]+)(?:$|&)
RewriteRule ^/?app/process\.php$ /app/api/%1 [R=301,QSD]

RewriteRule ^/?app/api/([^/]+)/?$ /app/process.php?public_url=$1 [END]
```

If you receive an internal server error (http status 500) for that then check your http servers error log file. Chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server, you may have to replace the `[END]` flag with the `[L]` flag which *probably* will work just fine in this scenario.

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only supported as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

---

UPDATE:

Based on your many questions in the comments below (we see again how important it is to be precise in the question itself ;-) ) I add this variant implementing a different handling of path components:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)public_url=([^&]+)(?:$|&)
RewriteRule ^/?app/process\.php$ /api/%1 [R=301,QSD]

RewriteRule ^/?api/([^/]+)/?$ /app/process.php?public_url=$1 [END]
```

Comment: Does the `app` folder have to be specified or could it be dynamic so it works in any folder?

Comment: We are running a dedicated in-house server. Can you tell me where inside the http server could this also be configured?

Comment: Certainly that can be implemented in a more dynamic manner. But for that you'd have to be more precise. It is not always a good idea to keep everything as generic as possible. You might want to ask another question about that (once things work for the specific case).

Comment: What do you mean by "where inside the http server could this also be configured"? Either you use a dynamic configuration file (as you currently do), or you use the http servers host configuration.

Comment: I'm getting 404 again. The `api` folder doesn't exist. When api is written what is means is that it needs to be directed to `process.php` script. Is that what is happening in the rules above?

Comment: When `/api/abcd1234/` is requested, it needs to fetch the results from the script `process.php?public_url=abcd1234` regardless of what folder it is placed in. While keeping the nice `/api/abcd1234/` url.

Comment: Your question clearly shows some `/app` folder on top level, here you don't mention that any more. Above rules redirect an incoming request to `/app/process.php?public_url=....` to `/app/api/.....` (in case some URL is still used from the outside, for example via a bookmark) and it internally rewrites requests to `/app/api/.....` to `/app/process.php?public_url=.....`, which is what you _probably_ want to have. Since you did not answer to my comment to the question that is what I assume at least.

Comment: Your result 3 comments further up suggests that the rewriting rules do _not_ get applied. So: are you certain that the dynamic configuration gets applied at all? Can you prove that?

Comment: They do get applied. When I enter the old url with the php get query, it changes to the new url. However it also removes the `/folder/` where `process.php` is placed. Which if possible it shouldn't touch the folder at all. Because it could be later used in another folder with a different name.

Comment: What "folder" are you talking about? Your question shows an `/app` folder, which is preserved by the rules above.

Comment: In this case `app` but shouldn't be folder specific. And it isn't. It's removing the `app` folder in this case and rewrites to `/api/abcd1234/` only.

Comment: The rules I posted do _not_ do that. Chances are that you have other, additional rules in place you did not tell us about. Or that you changed the rules I posted :-)

Comment: Haven't changed anything. Chrome is probably cashing stuff. Works in Safari just tried. However when I enter the original url, it doesn't retain the query `abcd1234`. What could be causing that?

Comment: Oh, indeed, sorry about that. I fixed the condition accordingly. I do have to apologize, I preserved your original condition pattern without thinking about it.

Comment: Thanks. And theres another issue, if there is a slash `/` after `/abcd1234/` it doesn't work. It only works without a slash after `/abcd1234`. Can it work both ways?

Comment: Sure, fixed that too, makes sense.

Comment: I would like to add a general hint. Please don't get this wrong, just trying to help: it appears as if you are currently not really trying to understand my rules, you just copy them. Your last question is a very good indication for that, you should be able to change that yourself. Sure, now and then everyone needs help and it is wise to ask for and accept it. But you also need to learn things, you need to be able to know what is actually going on, you need to stay in control yourself. So I would recommend that you dive into the official documentation of the rewriting module...

Comment: Thanks, i'm just starting to dabble with .htaccess apache stuff. And its rather confusing. So this is what I have `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)public_url=([^&]+)(?:$|&)
RewriteRule ^process\.php$ /app/api/%1/ [R=301,QSD]

RewriteRule ^api/([^/]+)/?$ process.php?public_url=$1 [END]`.  Now is it possible that `/app/api/%` is `/api/%` and it can automatically detect the folder it is in so it is dynamic and could be used in the root directory as well as other places?

Comment: Please understand the separate terms: `.htaccess` style files are dynamic configuration files. What you are currently dabbling with is rewriting rules, they depend on the rewriting module for the apache http server.

Comment: Certainly what you ask is possible, but I still do not fully understand what you actually ask: certainly you can have the "virtual" folder `api` on top level. You just remove the `/app` for that, right? About the "detect it automatically".... sure, but what for? what does "detect" mean here?

Comment: I placed an updated version of the rule set inside the answer which removes the `/app` path prefix from the URL. Not sure about the "detect" aspect...

Comment: I didn't explain myself properly. What I meant is, if I were to drop this configuration with the same script  in another folder, thats not called `app` it should work without alteration. The way it's updated now it doesn't know that before `/api/` comes another folder. I just want to retain the folder name without it being specifically named in the config cause it might change. If there is one to begin with as this might be placed in the root folder of the domain.

Comment: So the outer, visible URL should still contain that leading path component, whether it is `/app` or `/whatever`? Or shouldn't that be visible at all to the outside world?

Comment: It shouldn't even rewrite that far. Should only remove script.php and everything after. And situate them in a nice /api/abcd1234/ url. Whatever the folder if there is one, it shouldn't touch it at all. Not sure if thats possible...

Comment: This is _not_ possible in a direct manner, since it is unclear for an incoming request to `/api/abcd1234` to what internal script it should be rewritten. If no static name is implemented in the rewrite rule, then where does that information come from? You cannot solve that by placing the rule inside a physical folder in your document tree, since then it would not get applied to such a request at all. So: where does the information come from in such case? So where the folder name `app` in which the script actually is located?

Comment: Yeah I understand. Anyway, this will do great I think. Sorry for torturing you a bit. Really appreciate it though.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to get `.htaccess` to make the URL like this: `example.com/app/api/acbd1234`.

You don't do this in `.htaccess`. You change the URL in your application and then rewrite the new URL to the actual/old URL. (You only need to redirect this, if the old URLs have been indexed by search engines - but you need to watch for redirect loops.)

So, change the URL in your application to `/app/api/acbd1234` and then rewrite this in `.htaccess` (which I assume in in your `/app` subdirectory). For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite new URL back to old
RewriteRule ^api/([^/]+)$ process.php?public_url=$1 [L]
```

You included a trailing slash in your earlier directive, but you omitted this in your example URL, so I've omitted it here also.

If you then need to also redirect the old URL for the sake of SEO, then you can implement a redirect before the *internal rewrite*:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect old URL to new (if request by search engines or external links)
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)public_url=([^&]+)(?:$|&)
RewriteRule ^process\.php$ /app/api/%1? [R=302,L]

# Rewrite new URL back to old
RewriteRule ^api/([^/]+)$ process.php?public_url=$1 [L]
```

The check against `REDIRECT_STATUS` is to avoid a rewrite loop. `?:` inside the parenthesised subpattern avoids the group being captured as a backreference.

Change the `302` (temporary) to `301` (permanent) only when you are sure it's working OK, to avoid erroneous redirects being cached by the browser.

Comment: Rewriting the old to new results in 404 again. So the `api` folder doesn't exist. When api is written what is means is that it needs to be directed to `process.php` script. Is that what is happening now?

Comment: Additionally when, script.php is requested on its own it needs to redirect to a fictional folder `api`. So if `domain.tld/folder/script.php` is requested, it needs to go to `domain.tld/folder/api/`.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `/app/api/%1?` (missing `/app` directory) in the redirect (following the URL structure in your question). I've updated my answer. Yes, it's _rewritten_ to the `process.php` script (the URL in the address bar does not change).

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess rewrite returning Error 404
add this line your .htaccess make sure change domain name
Redirect 301 /login http://test.test.com